# ScrollView horizontal pagination only works on Android doesn't work on IOS react native expo cli

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, command-line-interface

Everyone.
I need your help.
I made one app with react native expo cli.
But one issue occurred.
I used the ScrollView for horizontal pagination.

```
*<SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView
        snapToInterval={wp("100%")}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        nestedScrollEnabled
        decelerationRate="fast"
      >
        {[...Array(this.state.pageCount)].map((num, index) => {
          return (
            <View
              key={"view" + index}
              style={{
                width: wp("100%"),
                height: "100%",
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row",
                flexWrap: "wrap",
                alignContent: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            >
              {this.state.categories
                .slice(index * 6, index * 6 + 6)
                .map((item, key) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    key={"touch" + key}
                    style={styles.itemStyle}
                    onPress={() => this.openModal(item)}
                    onLongPress={() => this.selectItem(item)}
                  >
                    <Image
                      source={{ uri: item.Foto }}
                      style={{ height: 120, width: "90%" }}
                      resizeMode="cover"
                    />
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{item.Precio}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{item.Gemas}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ))}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>*
```

But the pagination only works on Android Phone and doesn't work on iPhone.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `<ScrollView>` should have style `flex: 1`, to allow the view fit the screen size.
2. The width of the Views inside the Scroll should have a numerical value. A width of 100% inside a scrollview is undefined. Your approach should be related to the dimension of the screen.

```
// import dimensions lib
import Dimensions from 'react-native';

...
...
...

// capture the width of the screen
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('screen').width;

...
...
...

{[...Array(this.state.pageCount)].map((num, index) => {
  return (
    <View
      key={"view" + index}
      style={{
        width: screenWidth,
        height: "100%",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        flexWrap: "wrap",
        alignContent: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      {this.state.categories
        .slice(index * 6, index * 6 + 6)
        .map((item, key) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={"touch" + key}
            style={styles.itemStyle}
            onPress={() => this.openModal(item)}
            onLongPress={() => this.selectItem(item)}
          >
            <Image
              source={{ uri: item.Foto }}
              style={{ height: 120, width: "90%" }}
              resizeMode="cover"
            />
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{item.Precio}</Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{item.Gemas}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
    </View>
  );
})}
```